# How to handle a connection issue during a .GET request?

Tags: android, api, server

I have an android app which do some .GET calls by using [Ion library](https://github.com/koush/ion).

The server on each call returns a web page which i will then format and transform in real object data.

When the server receive the .GET request it locks the access to that request.

So if i make the .GET to `/example/?PAGE=1` the first request will return all needed data while if i will try to get it again i will receive a string like `LOCKED` until i will send another request like `/example/?UNLOCKPAGE=1`

The main issue of that is that the content of the page coult be very large and the device which is trying to fetch it could have a very bad network connection from which he could be disconnected at any time.

So if i make the .GET request and the device immediatly goes offline the server will lock the page but in facts the device didn't received that data.

How could a situation like this be solved?

I tought about a situation where on the .GET request the content is not locked until the device didn't send another request that confirms that he get all the data, but at this point what will happen if two devices will try to get both the same data and one of them get it first, will both of them get the data? Is that the right way?